# Pass PDF document to R function

Tags: r, function, api, pdf

I have a function in R (eg below). Which I need to expose as an API. The function currently expects a path pointing to a PDF file to be passed to it. It then scrapes that PDF file and does further work on the resultant string. The problem is that this is required in a live environment where the system will be downloading a PDF file and not necessarily storing it anywhere. The function / API would therefore need to have a PDF object passed to it rather than a path. I have no idea how to write the function so that it accepts a PDF object? I've read that BLOBs are objects representing binary data and thought that may be the route to go (have the system convert PDF file to blob and pass the blob to the function), but I'm not sure. Any ideas or links would be appreciated.

```
# path to the document
path = '//path/folder/file.pdf'



# function
function_absa_bank_statement_details <- function(path = "null"){
  
  
  if(path == "null"){
    
    result <- "No document"
    
  } else{
    
    raw_text <- pdf_text(path)
    list_lines <- strsplit(as.character(raw_text[1]), "\r\n")
    product_type <- str_trim(list_lines[[1]][17])
    account_number <- gsub("-", "", str_trim(function_get_substring(list_lines[[1]][9], ': ', 'end_line')))
    account_holder <- str_trim(list_lines[[1]][13])
    date_range <- gsub("/", "-", substr(str_trim(function_get_substring(list_lines[[1]][19], 'VIR TYDPERK: ', 'end_line')), 1, 23))
    start_date <- function_alter_string_date_format(substr(date_range, 1, 10))
    end_date <- function_alter_string_date_format(str_trim(function_get_substring(date_range, ' - ', 'end_line')))

  }
  
  
  return(list(
    "product_type" = product_type,
    "account_number" = account_number,
    "account_holder" = account_holder,
    "start_date" = start_date,
    "end_date" = end_date
  ))
  
  
}
```

Comment: I believe, you'll need to store the PDF as a temporary file for this to work.